# How to find a holomorphic branch of the function $(z^2-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ on the set $|z|>1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a function, $f(z) = (z^2-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, I wish to find a holomorphic branch of this function on the set $|z|>1$. I have used the definition of complex powers to deconstruct this function into an expression which is based on Log, but I cannot find a holomorphic branch of Log$(z+1)$ and Log$(z-1)$ on $|z|>1$

Comment: I have tried this strategy, however I cannot find a branch of Log$z$ which is holomorphic on $|z|>1$. Of course I am likely missing something here as you have suggested this strategy for a very good reason!

Comment: That is impossible (and I thought you might misinterpret my hint, so I'll rephrase/elaborate). Naively, $f(z)=z\left(1-\frac{1}{z^2}\right)^{1/2}$, and $\frac{1}{|z|}<1$. So, now can you define a holomorphic branch of $\log(1-\zeta)$ when $|\zeta|<1$? How would this help?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes. I must now find some angle $\theta$ such that $z \in L_{\theta} \implies |z| \leq 1$ i.e. find some angle of a half-line such that if $1-\frac{1}{z^2}$ lies on the half-line, then $z$ is inside the closed unit disc. But once again I am having problems with the Log$(z)$ term. Sorry if I am being a bit slow.

Comment: let's simplify somemore, and forget all the irrelevant junk. Answer first this simple question: Can you define a holomorphic branch of $\log(1-\zeta)$ with $|\zeta|<1$? How/why?

Comment: @peek-a-boo My thought process: $\text{Log}_{\theta}(1-\zeta)$ is holomorphic on the set such that $1-\zeta \in D_{0,\theta}$, which means the domain of holomorphicity for $\zeta$ is $D_{1,\theta-\pi}$. Since we know $|\zeta|< 1$, we need to find an angle such that the line cut never enters the open unit circle centred at the origin, which in this case is $[\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]$. I think this is the correct way so far?

Comment: I'm not sure what your notation means, but yea the point is the disk of radius $1$ centered at $1$ lies away from the origin, so $g(\zeta)=\log(1-\zeta)$ can be defined holomorphically when $|\zeta|<1$. Now, just define $f(z)=ze^{\frac{1}{2}g\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)}$, which is clearly holomorphic outside the unit disk.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes, I should clarify, $D_{1,\theta-\pi}$ is the set $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{z = 1 + re^{i(\theta - \pi)}: r \geq 1\}$, which is the entire complex plane with the half-line beginning at 1 making an angle of $\theta - \pi$ with the positive real axis. I get what you mean now, the $z$ can be taken out of the Log completely using standard rules of exponentials. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
 \operatorname{Log}(z) = \log(|z|) + i \arg z \quad (-\pi < \arg z < \pi)
$$
be the principal branch of the logarithm, defined on $D = \Bbb C \setminus  (-\infty, 0]$, that is the complex plane without the negative real axis.

Now let $G = \{ z : |z| > 1 \}$. For $z \in G$  is $1- \frac{1}{z^2}$ is in the disk with center $1$ and radius $1$, and that is a subset of $D$. Therefore we can define the function $f: G \to \Bbb C$ as
$$
 f(z) = z \exp \left(\frac 12 \operatorname{Log}\left(1- \frac{1}{z^2}\right)\right) \, .
$$
$f$ is holomorphic in $G$, with
$$
 f(z)^2 = z^2 \exp \left(\operatorname{Log}\left(1- \frac{1}{z^2}\right)\right) = z^2 \left(1- \frac{1}{z^2}\right) = z^2 - 1
$$
and therefore a holomorphic square root of $z^2-1$ in $G$.