# Branch of square root in a non simply connected domain

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: Find a function with the following properties:

1. $g$ is analytic in $\Omega = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \colon |z| > 2 \}$,
2. $[g(z)]^2 = 4z^2 - 9$ for all $z \in \Omega$.

The domain $\Omega$ is not simply connected, but why can a branch of square root of a holomorphic function exists in $\Omega$? Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: A branch of $\sqrt z$ cannot. A branch of $\sqrt {f(z)}$ for some $f$ can. The usual example is $\sqrt{z(1-z)}.$

Comment: You can write $f(z) = 4z^2 - 9 = z^2 \left( 4 - \frac{9}{z^2} \right)$ and then proceed as in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4645575/42969.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you so much for the clarification.

Comment: @MartinR thank you so much for the hints!